# unable to print the label and outline box of a cluster subgraph in graphviz

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot, graph-visualization

I am a newbie to graphviz and the DOT language. I was trying out generating graphs with cluster subgprahs. However, when I have clusters, each with node positions exactly specified in the script, graphviz does not generate the outline boxes or the labels for the clusters!
Specifically, if I have the following DOT script:

```
digraph G{
subgraph cluster0{
label="Cluster 0"
a->b
}
subgraph cluster1{
label="Cluster 1"
c->d
}
}
```

then the graph generated is:
[image: Graph generated with clusters when nodes positions are not specified by the user]

However, with the following DOT script, in which I specify the node positions of the 4 nodes exactly:

```
digraph G{
subgraph cluster0{
label = "Cluster 0"
a[pos="10,200"]
b[pos="100,200"]
a->b
}
subgraph cluster1{
label = "Cluster 1"
c[pos="10,100"]
d[pos="100,100"]
c->d
}
}
```

The graph generated is:
[image: Graph generated with clusters when nodes positions are specified by the user]

Notice that in this case, neither the outline box for the clusters nor the labels for the clusters are printed!! In this case, there is a clear demarcation between the 2 clusters as you can see - the clusters don't overlap, so in principle graphviz should not have a problem showing them, am I right?

How can I tell graphviz to draw the cluster outline boxes and labels no matter what?
Any help in this will be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: It is working for me. What version of dot are you using? What command are you using for conversion?

Comment: My dot version: dot - graphviz version 2.28.0 (20120313.1216). Command that I use for creation of graph: dot -Tpdf -O filename.dot

Comment: You sure it's producing the expected output for you? As in, is the arrangement of the nodes as expected given the pos values? Can you show the output you're getting... that'll be really helpful!thanks!

Comment: Here is the pdf file: http://www.filedropper.com/trialdot The source I used is exactly the same as in you non-working case.

Comment: Just saw your pdf... as you can see, it's not the expected output when you factor in the kind of relative placement of nodes I am looking to have with the pos values. This is exactly the output I am getting and also the same as the output the first code fragment in my question produces (i.e., without any pos values for the nodes), but what I want is like the second picture in the question with the cluster headings, etc.

Comment: ok, i clearly misunderstood the question. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot layout engine doesn't support the `pos` attribute.

To render a graph with positions of all nodes predefined, you should use `neato` or `fdp` with the `-n` option.

`neato` doesn't support clusters (though it [seems it should now](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-fixed-node-positions-ie-edge-routing-only)). Fortunately, `fdp`does!

Therefore, you may use the following command:

```
dot -Tpdf -Kpdf -n -O filename.dot
```

or

```
fdp -Tpdf -n -O filename.dot
```

Unfortunately, the positions of the nodes relative to the cluster are ok, but clusters still seem to get moved by fdp (`-n` switch didn't make a difference).

I didn't try with the latest version (I used 2.29.20120504), but if the latest doesn't work neither, this may be a case for a bug report.

Btw, since positions are assumed to be in inches, this will create a very large graph.

---

Output I get with fdp (with or without `-n` switch) - I added `size=20` to limit the image size:

[image: fdp output]

---

Alternative solution without using `pos`:

```
digraph G{
subgraph cluster0{
label = "Cluster 0"
{rank=same; a->b;}
}
subgraph cluster1{
label = "Cluster 1"
{rank=same; c->d; }
}

a -> c [style=invis];
}
```

Comment: I tried with the fdp layout engine, and it gives the same output as dot.
Do you also get the same output with fdp when you run the second piece of code in my question?

Comment: I added the output to my answer, considerably resized.

Comment: yes, I finally got this output, but, the clusters are are moved as you also noticed. I can't find any way to deal with this.
If I only want the cluster labels to appear, and don't care much about the boxes, is there some way to print some label text at particular positions in the graph - i.e., at the heading of the cluster as is usually printed by dot or fdp?

Comment: I added a solution to achieve the layout want using an invisible edge instead of fixed positions.

Comment: great, thanks! The reason, I was going for predefined positions was because in the graph layout I want (for a much bigger graph), some nodes need to overlap... until now, having fixed node positions was the only way I figured I could achieve that. Is there any other way to do this using fdp or neato?
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is rendering fine in svg on [viz.js](http://viz-js.com/). I am able to see borders around clusters.

Perhaps the graphviz version you use is old, an upgrade should fix the issue.